# Modify the driving directions Gmaps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This should be simple but not for me.
The displayed directions all work fine except the b point (end). The b marker displays 781-815 county road 555 but it should display 4011 Kings highway. in the following code,

```
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
```

Is there any way to do a replace on 781-815 county road 555 and display the kings highway address. I have Googled everything I can think of but all I can alert is Object Object. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I figured it out. create,
        directions2Display = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
Then added a Json lib file

        var string = JSON.stringify(response);
        var newString = string.replace("Turn", "Drive");
        myDirections = JSON.parse(newString);
        directions2Display.setDirections(myDirections);
        directions2Display.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

No errors and works a treat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. create,

```
    directions2Display = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

Then added a Json lib file

```
    var string = JSON.stringify(response); 
    var newString = string.replace("Turn", "Drive"); // replace what you need here
    myDirections = JSON.parse(newString); 
    directions2Display.setDirections(myDirections);
    directions2Display.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
```

No errors and works a treat. –

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' using the checkmark to the left.  This will inform other users that the problem has been solved and enable them to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for and I tried it but the Maps API shows this error "Error: TypeError: g[Lb] is not a function"